# Google Chrome suddenly doesn't show my User Profiles (to switch) anymore - why?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profile, user-data, google-account

My windows 10 notebook had to shutdown because of a low battery. When I restarted it, and started Chrome, it seemed that all my user data was gone. I looked into my User Data Folder ("C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"), and there are still the folders for seven Chrome user profiles which were created. But Chrome doesn't show these anymore in the upper right corner (so I can't switch them) ... how can that be !?

PS: I then logged in to my main Google Account to let it sync with Chrome. But now I have to login to every single website again (where I have been logged in automatically). Unfortunately, I don't have any windows recovery points I could try.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. All profiles gone, but the folders in AppData are still there.

To force Chrome to show them again, I executed this command for every profile I had:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 10"`

"Profile 10" being the name of the corresponding profile folder in AppData.

Chrome showed them all again afterwards.